# Как сделать ширину главного слайда 912px, четыре задних торчащими на 10px?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, frontend

Есть такой слайдер: https://codepen.io/shams-sujon/pen/xYeqrX

вот код, как требует ресурс:

```js
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    loop: true,
    speed: 1000,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 3000,
    },
    effect: 'coverflow',
    grabCursor: true,
    centeredSlides: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    coverflowEffect: {
        rotate: 0,
        stretch: 80,
        depth: 200,
        modifier: 1,
        slideShadows: false,
    },

    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },

})
```

```css
.swiper-container {
  width: 750px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.swiper-slide{
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://marveltheme.com/tf/html/appai/appai/img/app-screenshots/10.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://marveltheme.com/tf/html/appai/appai/img/app-screenshots/11.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://marveltheme.com/tf/html/appai/appai/img/app-screenshots/12.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
```

Но нужно чтобы главный слайд, то есть тот, что посередине был шириной 912px, а остальные 4 штуки выглядывали только на 10px? Как такое возможно реализовать?

Вот наглядный пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]